# Regex Expression assistance

Tags: regex

I'm trying to right a regex to break the following down into groups

```
0001 material tk.dup4.100
```

I've managed to write this which works fine:

```
(\d{4})\s(\w+)\stk\.(dup(\d+).(\d+))
```

However there is a possibility the 0001 will be immediately followed by a letter eg. 0001a and if I add that the match break. I do not need to capture the letter, just the digits before. Any help would be greatly appreciated

...

Thanks for the answers. Problem solved but I have one other issue i'd be very greteful for help with. If i want to capture another block at the front of the string (newbit 0001 material tk.dup4.100) that may or may not be present is that possible or will fail if not present?

Comment: You may replace the `\s` with `[\sa-zA-Z]`, but `(\w+)` will match the second letter of that word then. It is not quite clear what you really need here.

Comment: If you mean it could be: `0001a material tk.dup4.100`, you could just add `[a-zA-Z]*` after the first group and before `\s`.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

`(\d{4})[A-Za-z]?\s(\w+)\stk\.(dup(\d+).(\d+))`

Note the addition of `[A-Za-z]?`. `[A-Za-z]?` captures either 0 or 1 of any alphabetic character.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thanks Guys!

Comment: note that `[A-z]` will also match non-alphabetic chars like `[` and `_`

Comment: @ryugie good catch. I have edited my answer so that it only matches on alphabetic characters.